# Login to black screen with cursor

Tags: 13.10, lightdm

Sometimes, after login, it goes to a black screen without any hard disk activity while mouse cursor works.

I login to the terminal by pressing `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F4` and restart the X server using this command

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

Then login screen appears again and this time it goes to desktop after login.

How can I find the problem? I looked at system log but couldn't find any special thing.

Comment: Sometimes me also face the same problem in Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Same here, want to know whether it is a bug.